# Unity launcher lost focus

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, mouse, launcher

I'm having trouble using the unity launcher.

System info:

Ubuntu 16.04 (Intel)
Dual nvidia screen setup using Unity Desktop

Problem Description:

The Unity launcher bar, dash an switcher will not accept mouse focus when there are any open windows.  More precisely any portion of the launcher in front of another window will not accept focus. If the launcher is half over a window and half not over a window then the not half works fine.

The launcher appears in front but any mouse selection events occur in the window behind.

The keyboard shortcuts (help) window and switcher appear behind other open windows and can only be seen (fully) if no other windows are open.